# iOS App Update Discounts

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

I want to release an app for 2012.
Then I need to release a new app for 2013, to update the info.
( Like a catalog or something )
But since it's going to contain totally new info I don't want to offer a free update.

Is there a way to charge full price for the 2013 app for new users,
but offer a discount to users of the 2012 app?

Does Apple offer a way to do this, or has anyone come up with an interesting work around?

I guess now that I think about it, I could offer a generic app for FREE,
and do everything with In-App Purchases.

So when the next year info comes out, release a free update to the app that would include
the new data, and the option to purchase it via the IAP.

The thing I don't like about this model is it's misleading to the user.
The first time they install the app, it wont do anything until they buy the first
info bundle.  I was hoping there was a way to get around this.

Comment: "The thing I don't like about this model is it's misleading to the user." +1 for that feeling. It is a shame how many "free" apps basically require in-app purchases to do anything. There should be clear signage in the app store for those kinds of apps to distinguish them from real free apps (same for apps that display advertisements). Not going to happen of course, as those apps bring in a lot of money for Apple, too. I really wish Apple would implement paid upgrades instead of forcing developers into the shady world of IAP.

Answer (score 2):

You can have the app non-free and include this year's catalogue. Any later (or earlier) catalogues would be in-app purchases.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Apple supports that business model. In App Purchases or their publishing subscription model would be the way to go.